# Remove apps-scripts-notifications@google.com notification from Time-Based Script - Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a Time-Based trigger in a Google Sheet but it seems to fail quite a bit (I only run it 4 times a day...).

Is there a way when I create the trigger to remove the notifications?

```
ScriptApp.newTrigger("autoRefresh")
.timeBased()
.everyHours(6)
.create();
```

I found older topic asking the same question but it was 5 years ago and they said it couldn't be done... I was wondering if it was changed or still the same?

If it's still the same I will just point my users on how to remove the notification... (Just harder to fix this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you create the trigger manually; to do this, go into the editor, click the clock-looking button (between the `save` and `run` buttons) click the "Add trigger" button in the lower-right corner and set up your trigger.

On the right side of the menu you will see a "Failure notification settings" options, you can set it to "Notify me weekly", so you will only receive one email a week.

You cannot completely remove the notifications, but an alternative to this would be to create a filter in your gmail account to ignore/delete/archive these emails. Instructions for that can be found [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en).

Comment: The problem is that, this is a shared file with many users, and it's easier for me to set it for them.

Comment: If you set the trigger manually (not in the code), it will still apply to others, if you set a trigger for each of the 4 times you said you run it a day from the UI, the code will run and you will be the one who gets the notifications, you should not need to set anything for other users

Answer (score 0):

you get failure emails when your code stops in between due to some error (could be logical or server error).

Try adding try-catch in your function, this would not give app script failure notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the information, catch wouldn't work either, as the problem is that I get a TimeOut cause the request I'm using has a problem. I will have to fix this issue in another way as I found out what was the root cause, remove the email was just a plaster ;-) Now onto the real fix... But so far there is no way to remove this email in case of TimeOuts